# "xs:element" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xs:element>" i can´t find error

Tags: xml, xsd, end-tag

XML validation through xsd gives me this error, but i am not able to find where is my mistake with tags. I´d been trhough xsd and all tags look good for me. All entities seem to be closed, so I dont understand why end-tag of sequence is giving error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="pokemon">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nombre">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="codigo">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="[PK\-] [000-151]"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="foto" type="anyURI"/>
                <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="tipo">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Planta/Veneno"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Fuego"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Fuego/Volador"/>
                            <xs:enumeration vaule="Agua"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="fuerza">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-1000]{4}"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                <xs:element name="comentario">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: `<xs:element name="fuerza">` is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, the syntax highlighting on StackOverflow shows immediately where the error is.

*Well, it did. I've refreshed the page and that's no longer the case...*

Most decent XML editors will also make these problems easy to spot, at least for shortish files. Always use a good XML editor, to save your time and ours.

Comment: such a noob i am,
cheers